# where is the error in my code that make the sql query stop working

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drop-down-menu

i have 4 dropdown list that includes values retrieved from database,  then based on the selection of these values  i run second SQL  query to display all the related data to the selection.

i know that its a problem in the scope of the variable but i do not know how to fix it.

**example:** i have variable **$site_name** that is used in the dropdown list

```
 <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

             <?php
             global $site_name;

                 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                  foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                  {
                   $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                   echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                  } 
             ?>
```

this variable is checked in the top of the code using  **if isset**

```
 if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
echo "inside site name";
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
          }
          else { $site_name=""; }
```

then this variable must be compared in the SQL query in order to relate the user selection to the field name in the MYSQL database.

```
$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("
select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = '".$site_name."');
```

when i try to replace the **$site_name** by a **value** from the database everything work.

so i know that the problem is in the **$site_name** variable.

if anyone can help me i will appreciate that.

Comment: try var_dump($_POST['site_name'])  for check the real content

Comment: i tried your answer and it display the selected value from the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not closing the query. It starts with **"** and you're ending with **'**.

`'".$site_name"'` => `'".$site_name"'"`

If that doesn't work you could do `var_dump($site_name)` and see what it returns?

Also, don't insert a posted value straight into the database like that. Prepare the query first and then send it to the database

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
    LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
    on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
    LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
    on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
    LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
    on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
    on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
    where 
    site_info.siteNAME = '".$site_name"'");

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: @ Melvin Koopmans sorry for the missing quotes but is exist and i did not cope it  for the **var_dump($site_name)** it works fine and return the selected values but the problem is that the query do not takes this variable and compared i do not know why and how to fix this problem